# Printing numbers from 'char array' how to make them numbers not digits

Tags: c++

I have an expression, which is stored in a char array `char equation[101];`The input is via `cin.getline();`
I want to print all numbers from the expression, using a function `void printAllNumbers(const char* equation)`
for example: input : 24cd[*43-28/5*93}9(ks)

output:

```
24
43
28
5
93
9
```

How do I go about doing this: I go through the array, and if I find a digit, I print it. However, they come as digits, not as numbers.
void printAllNumbers(const char* equation){

```
  for (int i=0; i < strlen(equation); i++){
    if (equation[i]== '1' || equation[i]== '2' || equation[i]== '3' || equation[i]== '4'|| equation[i]== '5'|| equation[i]== '6'|| equation[i]== '7'|| equation[i]== '8'||equation[i]== '9')
    cout << equation[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: read and append to temp variable and then covert it to number when non-digit character is detected.

Comment: Show an example of what you mean that they show as digits not as numbers, do you mean that you actually want '2' to show as 50 (or maybe 0x32)?

Comment: The first sentence is a summary of what's wrong with the code. Use `std::string` instead of a character array, and `std::getline` instead of `std::cin::getline`. Use C++.

Comment: Well teachers don't allow that

Comment: You have figured out a way to detect digits and to print them. If all you want to do is show the numbers on separate lines in the output, then all you have left to do is figure out when to print newline characters to end each line. Hint: Do not print a newline (`endl`) after each digit. Print them only when a sequence of consecutive digits is done. How do you know when that happens?

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- re "newline (endl): -- they are quite different. `'\n'` is appropriate; the extra stuff that `std::endl` does is not needed here.

Comment: @PeteBecker: The OP used `endl` in their code; I mentioned it in parentheses to ensure they recognized they were printing a newline by inserting an `endl`. Parenthetical material does not always indicate a synonym; it was not used as an appositive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here some simplified variant using some old-fashioned c-style:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int len = 101;
  char s[len] = {'\0'};

  std::cin.getline(s, len);

  int i = 0;

  while (i < len) {
    char t[len] = {'\0'};  // here will the every next number be extracted
    int j = -1;

    while (isdigit(s[i]) && i < len && j < len) {
      t[++j] = s[i++];
  }

  if (0 <= j) {
    printf("%s\n", t);     // just print the number as string. here would the conversion to int, unsisigned int or whatsoever take place
  }

  ++i;
}
```

}

char t[] holds the string number. you can conver't it to number using the standard library functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try Somthing like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int j=0;
    char equation[101]{'2','4','c','d','[','*','4','3','-','2','8','/','5','*','9','3','}','9','(','k','s',')'};
    char number[j];

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(equation); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(equation[i]))
        {
            number[j++] = equation[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: better to avoid `unsigned` unless you have to.

Comment: @CroCo: There is nothing wrong with using `unsigned` in this code, except for the fact that it might be insufficient to index a very long string. But then a signed `int` would be no better.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that what the C++ creator said. It is good practice to stick with int.

Comment: This works however it uses string where I have to do it with char. How would you replace the last 3 lines of code to work for char

Comment: @EricPostpischil, some videos I've watched long time ago when Mr. Stroustrup was answering some questions.

Comment: @CroCo: You are imparting too much weight to a simplistic guideline.

Comment: @CroCo: It is wrong to take a simplistic guideline, give it too much weight, recommend it out of context, and judge answers by it.

Comment: @I'mnothuman, *crybabies*?! no need to be rude. In this site, people share their knowledge and accept sincerely any feedback to enhance the answer. I've flagged your comment since this language is not acceptable.

Comment: Just a joke, you are right on pointing out the best practices

Answer (score 0):

When you're scanning through the string you can be in one of two states: scanning a number and scanning something that's not a number. When you're scanning a number, accumulate the digits; when you hit something that isn't a number, write out the accumulated value. Like this:

```
const char *str = "24cd[*43-28/5*93}9(ks)";
bool in_number = false;
int value;
while (*str) {
    if (isdigit(*str)) {
        if (!in_number) {
            in_number = true;
            value = *str - '0';
        } else {
            value += *str - '0';
        }
    } else if (in_number) {
            std::cout << value << '\n';
            in_number = false;
    }
    ++str;
}
```